# Will the value of $t$ affect the row, column, and solution spaces?

Tags: vector-spaces

> Consider A = $\begin{bmatrix}4 & 2\\t & 1\\3&t\end{bmatrix}$.
> Is the column space of $A$ the same for all t$?$
> Is the row space of $A$ the same for all $t$?
>  Is the solution space of $Ax = b$ for a given $b$ in the span of the column vectors the same for all $t$? 
>   (Hint: Apply row reduction)

This is the question. I thought the column space of $A$ is not the same for all $t$. For instance, when $t = 0$, $\operatorname{span}{(4, t, 3), (2, 1, t)}$ will have only the vectors $(x, y, z)$ that satisfy the conditions $y = 1, z = 3$; when $t \ne 0$, $y$ does not have to be equal to $1$, $z$ does not have to be equal to $3$.

Knowing $b$ is in the span of the column vectors of $A$, which means the column space 
of A, I let $b = \begin{bmatrix}4c + 2k\\tc + k\\3c + tk\end{bmatrix}$. Then if $Ax = b$, $x = (c, k)$, it won't change with $t$'s changing. So, the solution space is the same for all $t$.

I couldn't say anything about the row space, I didn't apply row reduction and I'm not sure if the things I said constitute satisfactory answers to the questions.

Comment: I see you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions, yet.  Doing so is a courtesy, not only does it raise the reputation of the answerer, which is nice, but it also lets other people know that this question already has a satisfactory answer and thus they won't necessarily waste time looking over a question that you've already gotten an answer to.  P.S. to accept an answer, you click on the checkmark under the numbers on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The rank of your matrix can never be $\lt 2$ (try to make the two columns multiples of each other -- you can't), so the row space always spans $\Bbb R^2$, regardless of $t$.

The column space does depend on $t$.  Just choose two different values of $t$ and you're almost guaranteed to get two different column spaces.

The solution space will be dependent on $t$.  Let $b=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4c+2k \\ tc+k\\ 3c+tk \end{bmatrix}$.  If $t$ changes, then the $c$'s and $k$'s have to change to keep the two sides of the equation equal.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Row}A = \text{Col}A^T$$

So, row reduce $A^T$

$$\left[\begin{matrix}4 & t & 3\\2 & 1 & t\end{matrix} \right]\sim \left[\begin{matrix}4 & 2 & 2t\\0 & 2-t & 2t-3\end{matrix} \right]$$

If $t=2$ we can readily see the rowspace of $A$ is spanned by $(4,0)\sim (1,0)$ and $(4,1)$.

For $t\neq 2$ we can go farther:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}4 & 2 & 2t\\0 & 2-t & 2t-3\end{matrix} \right]\sim \left[\begin{matrix}4 & 0 & 2t-\dfrac{4t-6}{2-t}\\0 & 2-t & 2t-3\end{matrix} \right]$$

And you can see the rowspace is spanned by $(4,0)$ and $(0,2-t)$.

In either case, $\text{Row}A=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I didn't understand how you reduced $A^{T}$ to $\left[\begin{matrix}4 & 2 & 4\\0 & 2-t & 2t-3\end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: I think I copied and pasted a $4$ which I didn't change, the $4$ should have been a $2t$, fixed. Replace $R2$ by $2\cdot R2-R1$. Then Replace $R1$ by $R1+R2$